# WordPress - Adding a Post Type heading within a foreach loop when multiple post types are present

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm working on customizing the search results loop within WordPress. I'm displaying search results of two custom post types: Webinars and Research. I'd like to segment the Webinars and Research into their own sections with a heading for each section.

CURRENT LOOP

```
<?php
            if( have_posts() ){
                $types = array('webinars', 'research');
                foreach( $types as $type ) {                    
                    while( have_posts() ){
                        the_post();
                        if( $type == get_post_type() ){
                            get_template_part('loop-templates/content', 'search');
                        }
                    }
                    rewind_posts();
                }
            }             
        ?>
```

Any suggestions on getting all Webinars to live in their own div container, and all Research to live in their own div container?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply specify the post type (doesn't have to be in the loop) for each of them straight in the search template. if you want 2 different templates, 1 for webinars and 1 for research, you could do something like that:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ){

if ( 'webinars' === get_post_type() ):
echo '<h2>Webinars</h2>';
while( have_posts() ){
the_post();
//Template for webinars
the_title(); echo '<br/>';
};
endif;

if ( 'research' === get_post_type() ):
echo '<h2>Research</h2>';
while( have_posts() ){
the_post();
//Template for research
the_title(); echo '<br/>';
};
endif;

}; ?>
```

You can also restrict the search parameters to go further using `pre_get_posts`
from the function.php file:

```
<?php add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && in_array ( $query->get( 'post_type' ), array( 'webinars', 'research' ) ) ) {
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'webinars', 'research' ) );
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
};
} ); ?>
```

You can pretty much do anything just keep in mind that your search page must adapt itself to any search query, don't lock it to one specific post type.